# Algebraic description of double vector bundles.

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-k-theory

It is well known, by Serre-Swan theorem, that given a compact manifold M there is an equivalence of categories between the *category of vector bundles over M* and the *category of finitely generated projective modules over the space of smooth functions over M*.

> **Question:** Is there an analogous result for the category of double
>   vector bundles over a compact manifold
>   M? Is there a purely algebraic
>   description of a double vector bundle?

Roughly speaking a double vector bundle is a "vector bundle object" in the category of vector bundle. This statement is no precise and the concrete definition can be find in chapter 9 of Mackenzie's book "general theory of Lie groupoids and Lie algebroids" or in the paper K. Konieczna, P. Urbanski, *Double vector bundles and duality*, [arXiv:dg-ga/9710014v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/dg--ga/9710014). I don't write the definition in full detail because it is a little intrincate but we sketch it as follows:

A double vector bundle is a arrangement of manifolds $(\mathcal{B}; \mathcal{V}, \mathcal{H}; \mathcal{P})$ such that $\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{V}$ , $\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{H}$ , $\mathcal{V}\to \mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{P}$ are vector bundles, and such that 
structural maps of $\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{V}$ are vector bundles morphisms over the respective structural maps of $\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{P}$ from $\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{V}\to \mathcal{P}$. The same must be hold for the other structure of vector bundle over $\mathcal{B}$.

See the cited references for a more clear (and pictorical) definition.

Comment: What's a double vector bundle?

Comment: Apparently, doubled vector bundles were introduced in this paper by Jean Pradines: Géométrie differentielle au-dessus d’un grupoïde, C.R.Acad.Sci.Paris, série A 266 (1968), 1194-1196.  I have not read it.

Comment: Proffesor Figueroa-O'Farrill is right. I have wrote a little more about the definition of double vector bundle and a pair of references. I would like to say also that a double vector bundle is the underlying structure for the infinitesimal counterpart, in the sense of Machenzie, of a double Lie groupoid